# Unable to figure out 503 error when using rvest on working website that requires login

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to simulate the login page in order to login using an `rvest::session`.  When I go to the website, I get a `503` error, but my browser gives me no issues.

I then want to use the `html_form` to login using my login information.

```r
my_session <- rvest::session("https://nfc.shgn.com/historical/overall/baseball")
#> Warning in session_set_response(x, resp): Bad Request (HTTP 400).
```

I'm guessing it might have to do with the fact that the login url above refers to a different URL. Hoping someone can help me figure this out.